# Breaking up a large Excel procedure

Tags: excel, vba

I have two procedures that both run out of memory due to my data set in Excel exceeding a very vast amount.

```
Sub format()
Dim x, Y(), i&, j&, k&, s

x = Range("A1", Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft)).Value
With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
.CompareMode = 1
For i = 1 To UBound(x, 2)
    .Item(x(1, i)) = i
Next i

x = Application.Trim(Range("BL3", Cells(Rows.count, "BL").End(xlUp)).Value)
ReDim Y(1 To UBound(x), 1 To .count): j = 1

For i = 1 To UBound(x)
    If InStr(x(i, 1), "==") = 0 Then
        s = Split(x(i, 1))

        If .Exists(s(0)) Then
        k = .Item(s(0)): Y(j, k) = mid(x(i, 1), Len(s(0)) + 2)
        End If
    Else
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i
End With

[a2].Resize(j, UBound(Y, 2)).Value = Y()

End Sub
```

Above is the procedure I've been using to split/trim a column of data into several rows/columns.

Ive put data into two columns, each consisting of 60k rows each, what I need to do is once its read through BL, read through BO and continue where it left off putting the second row of data underneath the new row from whereever the first one finished

Comment: What is a "very vast" amount of data - how many rows/columns?

Comment: Have you tried using `Data->Text To Columns...`?

Comment: @TimWilliams I have one column "B3" that reads through about 391349 rows.

Comment: @Gaffi text to columns doesnt have the desired effect, the data for each section is split by === then fills from a - ap accross. the function works when the data set is smaller but obviously as its quite big I need a new way to work around it

Comment: above is the editted code, so two columns with 60k each, once its done the process through the first column I want it to read where it finished, row 1194 for example then do the same for column two writing underneath.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (UNTESTED) might work for you.  It avoids creating a huge 2D array by using smaller-size blocks.

```
Sub format()

Const BLOCK_SIZE As Long = 10000
Dim x, Y(), i&, j&, k&, s
Dim d As Object
Dim rOffset As Long
Dim xCount As Long

    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    d.CompareMode = 1

    x = Range("A1", Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Value
    For i = 1 To UBound(x, 2)
          'using Add: you probably want this to error if duplicates exist...
          d.Add x(1, i), i         
    Next i

    x = Application.Trim(Range("BL3", Cells(Rows.Count, "BL").End(xlUp)).Value)
    xCount = UBound(x)
    rOffset = 0

    ReDim Y(1 To BLOCK_SIZE, 1 To d.Count)
    j = 1

    For i = 1 To xCount
        If InStr(x(i, 1), "==") = 0 Then
            s = Split(x(i, 1))

            If d.Exists(s(0)) Then
                k = d(s(0))
                Y(j, k) = Mid(x(i, 1), Len(s(0)) + 2)
            End If
        Else
            j = j + 1
            If j > BLOCK_SIZE Then
                [a2].Offset(rOffset, 0).Resize(BLOCK_SIZE, d.Count).Value = Y()
                ReDim Y(1 To BLOCK_SIZE, 1 To d.Count)
                j = 1
                rOffset = rOffset + BLOCK_SIZE
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    [a2].Offset(rOffset, 0).Resize(BLOCK_SIZE, d.Count).Value = Y()

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm presented with an error on the : 'd.Add x(1, i), i' The key is already associated with an element of this collection which I can't figure my heading around

Comment: Aren't your headings unique?  That would only occur if there are more than one heading with the same content.  If you want to ignore that then go back to your previous Item() syntax, or use `If Not d.Exists(x(1,i)) Then d.Add, x(1,i), i`

Comment: the heading aren't unique, theres several either departments etc all the same but need to be manipulated several times, doesn't like the add function still or going back to my old function with the block, so I've settled for importing a block at a time of 60k rows to the sheet from which I just re-run this function and tell it to continue from the bottom one print out, thanks for all your help. one last question if I may at the end the [a2].offset is there a way I can go [a&lastRow] and it reads down to the last row in use as all the ways I've tried don't let me use the function there